# DB2 restore, rollforward issues

Tags: db2

I am trying to do an online backup of my db GS_DB in server1, then restore it to server2, and finally rollforward GS_DB in server2.

In server1, online backup:
GS_DB has already enabled archive log mode, (LOGARCHMETH1) = DISK:C:\GS_DB_ARCHIVELOG\

```
db2 backup db GS_DB online to <path> include logs
```

Scp the backup image to server2.

In server2, restore database:

```
db2 create db GS_DB2
db2 restore gs_db taken at <timestamp> into gs_db2
SQL2529W  Warning!  Restoring to an existing database that is different from the backup image database, and the alias name "GS_DB2" of the existing database does not match the alias name "GS_DB" of the backup image, and the database name "GS_DB2" of the existing database does not match the database name "GS_DB" of the backup image. The target database will be overwritten by the backup version. The Roll-forward recovery logs associated with the target database will be deleted.
Do you want to continue ? (y/n) y
DB20000I  The RESTORE DATABASE command completed successfully.
```

Connect to gs_db2:

```
db2 connect to gs_db2
SQL1117N  A connection to or activation of database "GS_DB2" cannot be made because of ROLL-FORWARD PENDING.  SQLSTATE=57019
```

Rollforward gs_db2:

```
db2 rollforward db gs_db2 to end of logs and complete
SQL1273N  An operation reading the logs on database "GS_DB2" cannot continue because of a missing log file "S0000266.LOG" on database partition "0" and log stream "0".
```

I have googled this error code and found the option logtarget in restore command maybe helpful, but I still don't understand what should be the path of logtarget?

```
db2 restore gs_db taken at <timestamp> into gs_db2 logtarget <???>
```

Am I missing something here? Should I also scp the archive log S0000266.LOG from server1 to server2? I suppose the include logs option in the backup command should have done it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The log files needed to rollforward the database to a minimum point in time (end of the backup) after restoring it from an online archive are included in this online by default.
You **have to** rollforward the database to a minimum point at time at least, when you restored from an **online** archive.
If you specify the `logtarget` clause, the log files from the archive will be extracted to the directory specified.
You can use this directory in the `OVERFLOW LOG PATH` clause of the [ROLLFORWARD DATABASE command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001978.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use following command to roll forward to end of backup.

`db2 rollforward   db gs_db2 to end of backup and complete`

Answer (score 0):

scp the logs to the archive log path of the restored database then 
db2 rollforward db mydb to end of logs and complete overlog path "(/home/db2/archivelogs)"